# AWS EMR s3a filesystem not found

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, amazon-emr

I am running an EMR instance. It was working fine but suddenly it started giving below error when I am trying to access S3 files from a Python Spark script:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o36.json.: 
   java.lang.RuntimeException: 
     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
       Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found
```

How can we resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was an issue with dependencies of spark. I had to add jars config in park-defaults.conf .

```
spark.jars.packages                com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.7.4,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.2
```

Please follow below link:
https://gist.github.com/eddies/f37d696567f15b33029277ee9084c4a0

Comment: In the case that you already have downloaded some packages, sometimes spark may does not download dependencies perfectly. in this case it is better to remove .ivy2/cash, .ivy2/jars and .m2/repository. take a look to this article: https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift/issues/244

Comment: Thanks @Moohebat for the article.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the hadoop-aws-3.2.1.jar (or any version above 2.7.10 based on your EMR version) and put it in /usr/lib/spark/jars
2. Download the latest aws SDK and put it in /usr/lib/spark/jars
3. update /usr/lib/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf
4. update spark.driver.extraClasspath - in the end add the full path of these 2 new jars, seperated by colon
5. run spark submit after that

Note: I used AWS EMR version 6.0+

Answer (score -1):

For Amazon EMR, use the "s3:" prefix. The S3A connector is the ASF's open source one; Amazon have their own (closed source) connector, which is the only one they support

Comment: I tried and now it is throwing java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: s3